# Coordinate array in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I have a form for creating an address, this address has an array of coordinates. But I don't know to generate the input to type for example 3 coordinates. Can be n coordinates, I'm planing to do that with jQuery (creating inputs). But for now I want to display the existing coordinates.

Here is the code:

Model

```
class Address
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps
    include Mongoid::Spacial::Document

    field :street, :type => String
    field :number, :type => Integer

    field :phone, :type => String

    field :delivery_zone, :type => Array
end
```

The erb.html

```
<%= form_for [:owner, :company,@address], :html => {:class => "form-horizontal"} do |f| %>
  <%= @address.delivery_zone.each do |dz|%>
    <% fields_for 'delivery_zone[]' , dz do |items| -%>

        ?? I don't know what to write here!!

    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<%end%>
```

What I'm looking for is to generate, for the field `delivery_zone` and each item in the array something like this:

```
<input id="address_delivery_zone[]"  name="address[delivery_zone][]" type="text" value="32.7 33.8" />
```

Comment: what are those "coordinates" ? latitude / longitude ? an internal code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not that familiar with Mongoid and Mongoid::Spacial, but i'll try to help.

As i understand your problem, you need every `address` to possibly have multiple `delivery_zones`, which i assume are geographical coordinates. I think it would be better to do something like :

```
class Address
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :street, :type => String
  field :number, :type => Integer
  field :phone, :type => String

  embeds_many :delivery_zones
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :delivery_zones
end

class DeliveryZone
  include Mongoid::Spacial::Document

  embedded_in :address
  field :coordinates, :type => Array, :spacial => true

  # accessors will help us manipulate the coordinates
  def latitude
    coordinates[:lat] # or coordinates[1] if you use the array
  end

  def longitude
    coordinates[:lng] # or coordinates[0] if you use the array
  end

  def latitude=( lat )
    coordinates[:lat] = lat
  end

  def longitude=( lng )
    coordinates[:lng] = lng
  end
end
```

you could then use `form_for` and `fields_for` as it is intended to be with nested resources , which i think (not guaranteed to work as-is) should be something like that :

```
<%= form_for @address do |address_form| %>
  <% @address.delivery_zones.each do |zone| %>
    <%= address_form.fields_for( zone ) do |zone_form| %>
       <p>Latitude :</p> 
       <p><%= zone_form.text_field :latitude %></p>
       <p>Longitude :</p> 
       <p><%= subform.text_field :longitude %></p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

More info about nested resources forms is available on [railscasts #197](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2?view=asciicast) and [railscasts #75](http://railscasts.com/episodes/75-complex-forms-part-3).

Comment: This is great, thanks. Also worth pointing out that the coordinates  should be converted to floats on saving if you're going to want to do any actual geo calculations

Comment: agreed. In fact, in proper OO `coordinates` should be a [value object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object). lat / lon values are clamped to +-180° and having one without the other is useless... Using composition would be a must here